# Android. X instead of y and y instead of x

Tags: android, view, ontouchlistener

```
public class SubPageGestureDetector extends View {

...

public void init(final SubPageFragment subPageFragment) {

    setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ...

            Log.e(TAG, "event = " + event.toString());

            return true;
        }
    });
}

//<--------------------->

public SubPageGestureDetector mGestureDetector;

...

mGestureDetector = (SubPageGestureDetector) vi.findViewById(R.id.fsp_gesture_detector);
mGestureDetector.init(this);

//<-------------------->

<ru.<...>.subpage.SubPageGestureDetector
    android:id="@+id/fsp_gesture_detector"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

It prints x instead of y and y instead of x. Has anyone encountered this problem?

View is within simple fragment. Fragment is within simple ViewPager. Pager is the only element of layout of Activity

```
    mGestureDetector = (SubPageGestureDetector) vi.findViewById(R.id.fsp_gesture_detector);
mGestureDetector.init(this);
mGestureDetector.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            ...

            Log.e(TAG, "event = " + event.toString());

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Works normally.

Comment: what???? You should explain more detailed and format Your code...

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain better? One thing I can tell you, is that in Android, the origin of your XY plane is the upper left corner of your phone screen. And also, the Y axis is inverted: positive Y coordinates of pixels increase as you move to the bottom of the screen.